# How to implement auto fixing a div like https://www.yahoo.com

Tags: javascript, html, css

In [Yahoo website](https://www.yahoo.com/), when scroll down, a blue part is fixed to the top, while if not scroll down, the blue part is not fixed.

How to implement this ?

May I try `onScroll` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$(window).scroll(function()` on the part which you want to be fixed.

Fiddle Demo : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/64X2j/)

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 100) {
       $('.sticky-header').addClass('fixed');
    }
    else {
       $('.sticky-header').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

If you want to apply the fixed part to the header replace the class name in the  `$(window).scroll(function(){}):` function.

Example for fixed Header while scrolling : [Demo-2](http://jsfiddle.net/64X2j/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I use inspect element and, apperantly it changes class when that "blue part" is not in view, 
so what it is doing (I guess) is changing the classes while it is in view and not in view, you can find if a div is in view and then change accordingly, "onscroll" is a great idea

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to bind to win scroll like this:

```
var element = $(YOURTOPELEMENT)
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scrollTop > element.offset().top) {
            element.css({
                position: "fixed",
                top: 0
            })
        } else {
            element.css({
                position: "relative"
            })
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it fixed just with css.

```
<div id="myHeader">Header stuff</div>

#myHeader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: maybe you misunderstand what I mean, please see http://jsfiddle.net/64X2j/ and scroll down. Thanks all the same!